# Cannot browse network on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, shared-folders

I have installed a clean copy of Ubuntu 18.04

If I try to load Network:/// I get 'This location could not be displayed'

In terminal, smbtree does infact give me the tree for the network and I can see the machines which have file shares I want to access

But if I try smb://computername/share, I once again get 'This location could not be displayed'

Answer (score 0):

On terminal

```
nautilus smb://computeraddress/share
```

Or

Gui in nautilus Other Locations either click on the computer name or enter `smb://computeraddress/share` in the space below.

[image: Other Locations]